How to find the minimum range at which some imaging payload/instrument can produce a clear image?
JWST's NIRCam can image deep sky objects so clearly. However if we notice the images of planets like Mars, Saturn or Saturn's's Moon-Titan, they don't appear to be much clear. Hence considering the specifications of NIRCam, how can I calculate the minimum distance at which an object should lie to get a clear image by NIRCam instrument.

You should provide some examples. It probably is not related to distance but the size. Titan may only cover a "few" pixels, so enlarging it to a larger size may make it less sharp.

Examples as in photos?

Infrared images will have fewer details than visible light images due to the longer wavelength.  The resolution limit of a scope is based on the diameter of the primary lens.

@GregMiller that likely is here already the whole answer

Different but related: Has Hubble ever focused on something close enough that it had to move away from being focused at infinity? and Did this satellite streak past the Hubble Space Telescope so close that it was out of focus? If so, how close was it?

It's not clear what you mean by "much clear" (compared to what?). But if you moved Saturn or Mars or Titan further away, their images would only get blurrier, not sharper.

Ok Sir. Noted..
